# How to send to the user other sites on same url conditionaly?

Tags: php, session, redirect

I'm making web store, and after user loggs in I want to show him other site on same url, depends on if he is an user or if he is shop administrator.
I store role of logged user in $_SESSION but I dont know how to pass to user other site. For example in express node.js you can make routing system using res.sendFile() conditionaly.

```php
<?php
    //Getting data
    if (isset($_POST['login'])){
        $login = $_POST['login'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['password'])){
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
    //starting session

    session_start();
    $_SESSION["logged"] = 0;

    // Connecing with db
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=zamowtosam user=postgres password=a")
        or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
    // Doing query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Osoby WHERE login='$login' AND pass='$password';";
    $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
    // Closing connection
    pg_close($dbconn);
    // Checking if we got any result in db
    if(pg_num_rows($result)<=0){
        echo 0;
        exit;
    }
    $_SESSION["rola"] = pg_fetch_assoc($result, 0);
    $_SESSION["logged"] = 1;
    $resultRole = $_SESSION["rola"];
    $resultArray = array($_SESSION["logged"], json_encode($resultRole));
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
?>
```

```js
//Here we check is typed login and pass matches with db 
function checkLogin(){
    const login = $("input[name='login']").val();
    const password = $("input[name='password']").val();
    if(checkValue(login, password)){
        //Here we start communicating with server
        $.post(
            "login.php",
            {login: login, password: password},
            function(result){
                const decoRes = JSON.parse(result);
                if(parseInt(decoRes[0])==1){
                    //If we logged we are redirected to app
                    alert("Zalogowano");
                    window.location.href = "main.html";
                }
                else{
                    //If no then not 
                    alert("Podany login lub hasło nie zgadza się");
                    console.log(result);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Use GET query strings.

Comment: Well, I first want to connect to the url and then ask server for a site.

Comment: The question is too vague. Without context with code on what you have so far it will be very hard to help.

Comment: Then iframes might be the only way.

Comment: I added code...